# Add three numbers and display result in textbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i was just trying to write a code that will use 3 input fields and show their sum into result field. If a person put data in field 1, the result field should show the data in result field and when user put data in second field, result field should show the sum of field 1 and field 2 and when user put data into field 3, their sum should be show on result field. I write below code but not got any success. I am a new learner.

```
<body>
Field 1: <input type="text" id="num1" onkeyup="sum();" > </br>
Field 2: <input type="text" id="num2" onkeyup="sum();" > </br>
Field 3: <input type="text" id="num3" onkeyup="sum();"> </br>
Sum: <input type="text" id="final"  />



<script type="text/javascript">

function sum()
{


var w = document.getElementById('num1').value;

var x = document.getElementById('num2').value;

var y = document.getElementById('num3').value;

var z=parseInt(w)+parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);


document.getElementByID('final').value=z;

}       
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery (if you don't know how to use it, please comment here).

Comment: Try fixing this `document.getElementByID('final').value=z` typo, to `getElementById`

Comment: thanks dear. I just correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

(1) Small typo in your last line, you used getElementByID instead of getElementById

(2) You need to account for the case where there is no value, one way to do this is to or it with 0 (which evaluates to 0 if there is no value).

Here is a working example:

```
function sum()
{
  var w = document.getElementById('num1').value || 0;
  var x = document.getElementById('num2').value || 0;
  var y = document.getElementById('num3').value || 0;

  var z=parseInt(w)+parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);

  document.getElementById('final').value=z;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yq60qad0/

Comment: Thanks mate. I spend a day on this. Glad to get working code.

Comment: Just glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. =>

```
document.getElementByID('final').value=z;
```

should be Id, not ID

Comment: thanks for the correcting me. But still when i put input in first two fields result field shows NaN...how to handle it?

Comment: It's because all the numbers are not defined yet to sum them up. NaN means "not a number", Your code is trying to add up "5", "8", and undefined, for example. Your code works properly only when all three inputs are done.